# Find missing rows by timestamp + ID with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I try to find missing timestamp. Here are a lot of solutions to fix this single problem. Nevertheless I also want to find "where" timestamp by ID is missing.

So for example the test-dataset would look like this:

```
elemuid timestamp
1232    2018-02-10 23:00:00
1232    2018-02-10 23:01:00
1232    2018-02-10 22:58:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:40:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:39:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:37:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:35:00
```

And the solution should be like:

```
elemuid timestamp
1232    2018-02-10 22:59:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:38:00
1674    2018-02-10 22:36:00
```

My problem is that I can only use `dplyr`, because I would like to use this code also in `sparklyr`.
I would be really happy for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simplicity let's assume you've already followed the [instructions from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49871925/6910411), and computed [minimum and maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881671/6910411) (`min_max`) [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in seconds.

The remaining steps are quite similar to the ones we followed before:

- Generate range of values:

  ```
  epoch_range <- spark_session(sc) %>% 
    invoke("range", as.integer(min_max[1]), as.integer(min_max[2]), 60L) %>%
    invoke("withColumnRenamed", "id", "timestamp")
  ```
- Compute distinct `elemuid`

  ```
  elemuids <- df %>% select(elemuid) %>% distinct() %>% spark_dataframe()
  ```

Now, we want to generate a reference table as a Cartesian product of the range and unique ids:

```
ref <- epoch_range %>% 
  invoke("crossJoin", elemuids) %>% 
  sdf_register() %>%
  mutate(timestamp = from_unixtime(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

You might be tempted to use more `dplyr`-ish method:

```
sdf_register(epoch_range) %>% mutate(dummy = 1) %>% 
  left_join(sdf_register(elemuids) %>% mutate(dummy = 1), by = "dummy") %>%
  select(-dummy)
```

This would work fine if size of the product is small (in that case Spark should use broadcast join), but will cause complete data skew otherwise so it is not safe to use in general.

Finally we'll outer join data as before:

```
ref %>% left_join(df, by = c("timestamp", "elemuid"))
```

to fill out things, or (as [already explained in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955347/6910411) provided by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun)) anti join to remove missing points:

```
ref %>% anti_join(df, by = c("timestamp", "elemuid"))
```

Comment: Ahhh..perfect! That's all I've been looking for. Meanwhile I tried my luck with `spark_apply()` to extend _sparklyr_-functionality, but unfortunately it did not work so well. All I got was an _error with status: 255_. Nevertheless I would like to thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why is this method not working with millions of rows? the ref-dataset looks good, but count of dates per ID is the same like after join..?

Comment: There might be no missing values. In general try to reduce problem to MCVE. For example does it happen when you take a small sample?

Comment: but if _anti-join_-table is as large as ref-table it means that all dates are missing and that's impossible..

Comment: Huh... Are you sure that types match? I mean there is no weird implicit conversion on the way.

Comment: And how does the execution plan look like? (you can use `optimizedPlan` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614889/6910411)).

Comment: ah, I found an error. so if one ID with a timestamp is already used, then he does not check whether the timestamp is also present with the other ID. I am looking for a solution

Comment: the result from the above dataset is always pairwise missing dates by IDs. So there should be also e.g. `1232   2018-02-10 22:40:00`, but it is not, because the date is already at the other ID.

Comment: It worked, but only when i do a collect() on ref-dataframe and then copy it back to spark-context.

Comment: That's unexpected. Do you get any warnings in the log?

Comment: no, nothing at all. It seemed to work, but only in local spark context. At a yarn-client it is just the same as before. Do I have to disable `crossJoin` afterwards? I can't imagine what the problem could be, because _ref-dataset_ looks just perfect, but the result after `anti_join` is just the same as _ref_ and that's not possible.(I checked som dates by hand..)

Comment: No, actually you don't even have to enable it as we use `crossJoin` explicitly (before I thought about SQL version like `SELECT * FROM epoch_range JOIN elemuids`, then it would be required). TBH it sounds like a bug. We could try rewriting this by hand with outer join, but since I cannot reproduce the problem, I cannot say it make any difference. And if you can get MCVE yourself, and confirm it with supported API, then I'd recommend opening a JIRA ticket (I don't think it is introduced `sparklyr`)

Comment: That was not the answer I was hoping for, but that's the way it is. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'll experiment with this when I have a spare moment, and see if I can reproduce this thing somehow. Which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: That would be awesome! spark 2.2.0.

Comment: Huh, could you try updating to the latest 2.2 release (2.2.1)?

Comment: Yes, I can use 2.2.1, because it is supported by dataProc. But as far as I can tell it has not changed result.

Comment: Your method works excellent..I was dumb and used the wrong date-format without milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `anti_join`.  Assuming that the 'timestamp' column is not a Datetime object, we convert it to `POSIXct`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df1 %>%
          mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp))
```

grouped by 'elemuid', use `complete` to expand the 'timestamp' by 1 minute and do an `anti_join` with the original dataset

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(elemuid) %>% 
    complete(timestamp = seq(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), by = "1 min")) %>% 
    anti_join(df1)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups: elemuid [?]
#   elemuid timestamp          
#     <int> <dttm>             
#1    1232 2018-02-10 22:59:00
#2    1674 2018-02-10 22:36:00
#3    1674 2018-02-10 22:38:00
```

Comment: that's a straightforward and intuitive answer. As I mentioned my problem is that I can only use `dplyr`. `ymd_hms` and `complete` are not supported functions by sparklyr. I asked a similar question a few days ago: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871925/complete-time-series-with-sparklyr). Now I don't know how to change the answer to full-fill my task with ID.

Comment: @luks_wi  Would `base R` functions like `expand.grid` and `as.POSIXct` work? i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp))`

Comment: @luks_wi  I thought these functions would work because they are part of the `tidyverse`

Comment: unfortunately you can't use them within a spark-dataframe.. :/ I would have to copy it to an R-dataframe, but then I am losing the speed of spark. The exception is always: _Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'as' not found;_

Comment: what error do you get? do you run it in a spark-context?

Comment: Yes, i was running in that spark-context.  The error is `error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: could not resolve `RANGE` to a table-valued function; lin`

Comment: That's interesting, because it works for me. Maybe you didn't install `glue`-package. That's all I can suggest and imagine

Comment: I have all the packages installed'

Comment: @akrun That's weird. How about `spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("range", as.integer(min_max[1]), as.integer(min_max[2])) %>% sdf_register()` where `sc` is `spark_connection` object?

Comment: Sounds like [SPARK-20145](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20145). Regarding the question - to make it work in Spark you'll need cross product with distinct IDs, but you have to make sure you'll do it with SQL, not a dplyr way with  dummy, otherwise you'll end up with a single partition, so it is probably easier to write it in SQL all the way.

Comment: Oh, and enable [cross joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000050/6910411).

Comment: @user6910411  Please post it as a solution

Comment: @user6910411 where do I have to write the command `df1.crossJoin(df2)`. What does it mean? And how to work with different start-/end-timestamps by group like: id: 10, timestamp: "2018-06-06 10:21:00", id: 5, timestamp: "2018-06-06 10:21:01". So do I have to create a _reference-dataset_ for all groups?