# Transform dataset with empty data for dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset with date,accountid and value. I want to transform the dataset to a new dataset where if accountid is not present in a particular date then add a accountid with value of 0 against that date.Is this possible

```
    val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2018-01-01", 100.5,"id1"),
  ("2018-01-02", 120.6,"id1"),
  ("2018-01-03", 450.2,"id2")
  )).toDF("date", "val","accountid")
    +----------+-----+---------+
|      date|  val|accountid|
+----------+-----+---------+
|2018-01-01|100.5|      id1|
|2018-01-02|120.6|      id1|
|2018-01-03|450.2|      id2|
+----------+-----+---------+
```

I want to transform this dataset into this format

```
+----------+-----+---------+
|      date|  val|accountid|
+----------+-----+---------+
|2018-01-01|100.5|      id1|
|2018-01-01|  0.0|      id2|
|2018-01-02|120.6|      id1|
|2018-01-02|  0.0|      id2|
|2018-01-03|450.2|      id2|
|2018-01-03|0.0  |      id1|
+----------+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create reference

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val Row(minTs: Long, maxTs: Long) = df
  .select(to_date($"date").cast("timestamp").cast("bigint") as "date")
  .select(min($"date"), max($"date")).first

val by =  60 * 60 * 24

val ref = spark
  .range(minTs, maxTs + by, by)
  .select($"id".cast("timestamp").cast("date").cast("string").as("date"))
  .crossJoin(df.select("accountid").distinct)
```

and outer join with input data:

```
ref.join(df, Seq("date", "accountid"), "leftouter").na.fill(0.0).show
// +----------+---------+-----+      
// |      date|accountid|  val|
// +----------+---------+-----+
// |2018-01-03|      id1|  0.0|
// |2018-01-01|      id1|100.5|
// |2018-01-02|      id2|  0.0|
// |2018-01-02|      id1|120.6|
// |2018-01-03|      id2|450.2|
// |2018-01-01|      id2|  0.0|
// +----------+---------+-----+
```

Concept adopted from [this `sparklyr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004545) by [user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411).

Comment: Excellent ! it works. One question does  the cross join function performance intensive, lets say if the original dataset contain 1M record?

Comment: Complete process is expensive due to shuffles and conversion from sparse to dense, but you cannot really avoid the cost with desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use a `udf` function to get your requirement fulfilled.**

But before that you will have to *get the complete set* of *accountids* and get it *broadcasted* to be used in `udf` function.

The *returned array* from `udf` function is to be *exploded* and *finally select the columns*.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val idList = df.select(collect_set("accountid")).first().getAs[Seq[String]](0)

val broadCastedIdList = sc.broadcast(idList)

def populateUdf = udf((date: String, value: Double, accountid: String)=> Array(accounts(date, value, accountid)) ++ broadCastedIdList.value.filterNot(_ == accountid).map(accounts(date, 0.0, _)))

df.select(populateUdf(col("date"), col("val"), col("accountid")).as("struct"))
    .withColumn("struct", explode(col("struct")))
    .select(col("struct.date"), col("struct.value").as("val"), col("struct.accountid"))
  .show(false)
```

And of course you would need a `case class`

```
case class accounts(date:String, value:Double, accountid:String)
```

which should give you

```
+----------+-----+---------+
|date      |val  |accountid|
+----------+-----+---------+
|2018-01-01|100.5|id1      |
|2018-01-01|0.0  |id2      |
|2018-01-02|120.6|id1      |
|2018-01-02|0.0  |id2      |
|2018-01-03|450.2|id2      |
|2018-01-03|0.0  |id1      |
+----------+-----+---------+
```

**Note: value keyword is used in case class because reserved identifier names cannot be used as variable names**