# Is there a way to fill in missing dates with 0s using dplyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a dataset like this:

```
id  date     value      
1   8/06/12    1         
1   8/08/12    1         
2   8/07/12    2         
2   8/08/12    1
```

Every id should a have a value for every date. When an id is missing a particular date, that row needs to be added with a value of 0. E.g.,

```
id  date     value      
1   8/06/12    1   
1   8/07/12    0      
1   8/08/12    1  
2   8/06/12    0         
2   8/07/12    2         
2   8/08/12    1
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add the rows with 0s. There's a good solution here: [R - Fill missing dates by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633460/r-fill-missing-dates-by-group). However, I can't use the `tidyr::complete` function because I'm using `sparklyr` and, as far as I know, need to stay within `dplyr` functions.

Comment: [Complete time-series with sparklyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49871925)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sparklyr`, you must use Spark functions. This is a job for `coalesce`. First you have to fill out all the pairs of ids and dates you expect to see, so maybe something like:
(**edit**)

```
all_id <- old_data %>% distinct(id) %>% mutate(common=0)
all_date <- old_data %>% distinct(date) %>% mutate(common=0)
all_both <- all_id %>% full_join(all_date,by='common')
data <- old_data %>%
  right_join(all_both %>% select(-common),by=c('id','date')) %>%
  mutate(value=`coalesce(value,0)`)
```

I have assumed you have all the dates and ids you care about in your old data, though that might not be the case.

Comment: I can create a table of all the required dates. I'm going to try this right now. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Now that I think about it, my code will not do exactly what you want; you need to right join on all of the dates and IDs...

Comment: Gotcha. I'll change that.

Comment: `full_join` seems safer than `right_join`, just in case there are dates missing from `all_date` they won't be silently dropped.

Comment: My sparklyr motto is: _twelfth time's a charm_.

Comment: When I test the full_join, I get an error  because there's no common variables. What am I missing?

Comment: Great solution. But I think the third line of code (full_join) will not work because `all_id` and `all_date` have no common variables.

Comment: I guess I can just add a common variable to do the full join. e.g.,  all_id <- old_data %>% distinct(id) %>% dplyr::mutate(join_placeholder = 1)
all_date <- old_data %>% distinct(date) %>% dplyr::mutate(join_placeholder = 1). I'm going to try that

Comment: Right you are. Edited again to have a common field.

Answer (score 1):

**`expand.grid()`**

Use `expand.grid()` to create all combinations of `id` and `date`. By the way, notice to transform your date to the class `Date` by `as.Date()` otherwise it will be a meaningless string.

```
df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%y")) %>%
  right_join(expand.grid(id = unique(.$id), date = unique(.$date))) %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(value, 0L)) %>% 
  arrange(id, date)

#   id       date value
# 1  1 2012-08-06     1
# 2  1 2012-08-07     0
# 3  1 2012-08-08     1
# 4  2 2012-08-06     0
# 5  2 2012-08-07     2
# 6  2 2012-08-08     1
```

---

**Reproducible Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), date = c("8/06/12", "8/08/12", 
"8/07/12", "8/08/12"), value = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: `expand.grid` will work well on `data.frame`, but it will have to be copied into spark. I believe the magic incantation to do that is to use the `copy` parameter in a join. Something like `right_join(my_local_df,by=..., copy=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestion! I didn't notice that before seeing your comment.